# Mac OS: Why does `echo $JAVA_HOME` output wrong path?

Tags: java, bash, macos, command-line

I got the following error when running a React Native app:

`ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /usr/local/Cellar/openjdk@11/11.0.10/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home`

When I run `/usr/libexec/java_home` I get `/usr/local/Cellar/openjdk@11/11.0.14.1/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home`, so 11.0.14.1 is my installation.

I looked in `bash_profile` for where `JAVA_HOME` was set, and found `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v11)`. When I run `/usr/libexec/java_home -v11` it outputs `/usr/local/Cellar/openjdk@11/11.0.14.1/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home`.

Also note, when I change `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v11)` to `/usr/local/Cellar/openjdk@11/11.0.14.1/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home`, open a new command prompt and run `echo $JAVE_HOME` it does return `11.0.14.1`, but then when I change it back to `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v11)`, open a new command prompt and run run `echo $JAVE_HOME` it *also* returns `11.0.14.1`.

**What I Want To Know:**

1. Why does `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v11)` seem to set `JAVA_HOME` to `11.0.10` in `bash_profile`, but when I run `/usr/libexec/java_home -v11` from the command line it outputs `11.0.14.1`?
2. How can I modify `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v11)` in `bash_profile` in order to get the correct up-to-date installation?

Comment: Are you sure you are actually working in bash? What do you get when doing echo $SHELL?

Comment: @RealSkeptic Yes, I get `/bin/bash`

Comment: Also, the profile is only run when logging in. When just opening a new shell, it usually runs just `.bashrc`.

Comment: `echo $SHELL` shows the default shell set for your user account, but that can be overridden in many ways; `echo $BASH_VERSION` is a better way to find out if you're actually running bash.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Running `echo $BASH_VERSION` gives `3.2.57(1)-release`

Comment: That's the standard one that comes with macOS, so that's not a problem. I'd add `echo "JAVA_HOME set to: $JAVA_HOME" >&2` to your bash_profile immediately after the `export JAVA_HOME` command, and then open a new Terminal window, to see if that's actually where it's getting set wrong.